# Running convert Raster to Point Features in arcpy returns an error

Tags: arcpy, raster, point, batch, regression

I'm trying to convert a bunch of rasters to point features to further build a regression of those. Is it possible to do that without a conversion using arcpy?
If not what am I doing wrong converting?

```py
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Users/Sandro/Desktop/Bachelorarbeit/Data/clipped_season/TESTEVI_Heide_clip_season"

rasListe = arcpy.ListRasters()

for ras in rasListe:
    outpoint = r"C:/Users/Sandro/Desktop/Bachelorarbeit/Data/EVI_shp"+ ras.replace('.tif','.shp')
    arcpy.RasterToPoint_conversion(ras,outpoint)
```

Comment: Do you get an error or what is wrong? Are you going to use ArcGIS for the regression? You can use modelbuilder instead of arcpy. And/or switch tool to [RasterToNumPyArray](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/rastertonumpyarray-function.htm)

Comment: This is the Error I get: : "ERROR 999999: Something unexpected caused the tool to fail"

Comment: Try switching from shape output to features in a file geodatabase. Maybe the Point output exceed the shapefile limit of 2GB. Does the output of `print outpoint` look like a valid path+name of a shapefile? Use `os.path.join` instead of + when combining path and filenames

Comment: I already did the RasterToNimpyArray but I couldnt find a tool to create a regression based on arrays. `os.path.join` somehow doesn't work. This is what I did: `outpoint = os.path.join("C:/Users/...", ras.replace('.tif','.shp'))`. The Error says that `os` is not a variable.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work with the NumpyArray method. This is the Code:

```
import arcpy
import numpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Users/..."
rasListe = arcpy.ListRasters()
for ras in rasListe:
arrays = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(ras, nodata_to_value=0)

print(arrays)
[[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
...
```